# Field with @OneToOne annotation in super class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, one-to-one

I have class `Document`, which contains field `Ad ad` with `@OneToOne` annotation.
Class ResultDocument extends Document, `JOINED` inheritance strategy is applied. When I start my app, I get error:
`org.hibernate.MappingException: property [ad] not found on entity [ua.translate.model.ad.ResultDocument]`

Please, explain me cause of this error.

class Document:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INIT_DOCUMENT_TEST")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Document {


@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "standart",initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "standart",strategy =GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_ID")
private long id;

@Lob
@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_FILE",nullable = false)
private byte[] file;

@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_FILE_NAME",nullable = false)
private String fileName;

@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_CONTENT_TYPE",nullable = false)
private String contentType;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_AD_ID")
private Ad ad;
.....
}
```

class ResultDocument:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESULT_DOCUMENT_TEST")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name= "result_document_id")
public class ResultDocument extends Document{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSLATOR",nullable = false)
    private Translator downloader;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that you shouldn't extend from Document, because if you are using hibernate or JPA the technology use the relation without perform inheritance.

Comment: Please, explain detailed. I don't understand, what you mean.